# I installed Ubuntu alongside OSX and now OSX will not start.

Tags: 12.04, mac

I installed Ubuntu "alongside OSX Lion," but now OSX refuses to start.  I originally intended to use rEFIt to dual boot Linux, but that process failed when I downloaded "alongside" Ubuntu.

Ubuntu gives me an option at the beginning to start all these different OS's, but only two include OSX (a 32 and a 64 bit version).  When I click on the 32 bit it does nothing, but when I click on the 64 bit it gives me three beeps and a black screen.  What should I do now? Because I checked in Ubuntu and all my OSX files are still there.

Comment: Note I just got off the phone with apple support and they say I would have to go to the apple store about 7-9 hours away and still pay to get it reaired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have OS X Lion nstalled, you might:

- boot your Mac by holding the [X] key to force OS X startup;

or

- boot your Mac by holding the [COMMAND] and [R] keys to start the recovery mode;

as explained at the following link: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343

Comment: Thank you verry much, you have solved my prolem.  I would not have been able to fix it without your help.  I am extreamly greatful for it.